# Splitting a GPS Point into Latitude and Longitude Regular

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string representation of a GPS point...

```
(40.714353, -74.005973)
```

How can I perform a string split to obtain both the latitude and longitude as separate tokens - without any superfluous characters (spaces and brackets) using Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions:

```
>>> str = "(40.714353, -74.005973)"
>>> tuple(float(x) for x in str.strip('()').split(','))
(40.714353, -74.005973)
```

If you want to have strings instead of numbers, use `x.strip()` instead of `float(x)`.

---

A regular expression solution could be:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r"^\(([-\d.]+), ([-\d.]+)\)$", str)
>>> m.group(1)
'40.714353'
>>> m.group(2)
'-74.005973'
```

This uses [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to extract the information.

See also the [`re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: Works perfectly!  The regular expression answer was appreciated.  I could have used the non-regex solution but I was more interested in learning how to apply regexs in this instance.

Answer (score 8):

You may use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html?highlight=literal#ast.literal_eval) to parse the string:

```
>>> import ast
>>> coord = "(40.714353, -74.005973)"
>>> ast.literal_eval(coord)
(40.714353000000003, -74.005972999999997)
```

Comment: `lat, long = ast.literal_eval(coord)` is totally sufficient.

Comment: That's what I meant. I don't know why I pasted in this overcomplicated  snippet. ;)

Comment: I've removed the overcomplicated snippet. Feel free to rollback for any reason.